# EDGE_FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED when deploying an hydrogen application in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, vercel, hydrogen, shopify-hydrogen

When I am deploying my Hydrogen based Shopify application into Vercel. I am getting this error
EDGE_FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED

when seeing on logs it tells this.

[image: 1]

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Hydrogen 2.0, You can follow the article below to deploy Hydrogen 2.0 to Vercel:
https://shopifyhydrogen.io/blog/how-to-deploy-shopify-hydrogen-2-to-vercel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).